# How do I knock out an armoured target?

Tags: heat-signature

For a personal mission, I have to capture an armoured enemy. I know how to knock enemies out and I have a few armour-piercing weapons, but nothing that is both armour piercing and non-lethal.

Is there such a weapon, or are there other ways to capture armored enemies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few options that come to mind (and I did a bit of googling).

You can get armor piercing concussive guns; obviously non-lethal.

There's also a very rare drop called Fiasco's Facebreaker that is essentially an armor piercing concussion hammer.

An alternative way to deal with it (although much harder to pull off, this doesn't require rare/unique items) could involve [glitch traps](https://heatsignature.gamepedia.com/Glitch_trap).  All you have to do is lure them (or use a swapper) into a glitch trap that is aimed outside of the ship.  This should knock them out.  Then you have to quickly bring your pod over and pick them up before they die in space.  I'm *pretty sure* this will work.  I've personally only tried it ~2 times and failed at getting the pod to them both times though; so no promises.

As confirmed by Studoku in comments, throwing them into space works.  He used broken windows; which is even better because it doesn't require anything specific.

Comment: I can confirm that throwing them into space works since that's what I did. I did it by breaking a window though, which is easier since this also throws you into space.

Comment: @Studoku Thanks - added to the answer for additional resources.

Comment: having the angel pod helps significantly with catching both you and other targets in space. Press E and it sucks in all people in an area bigger than some of the largest ships to it. If you get them and you out of the same window near the same time (by say blowing it up with both of you in the room), you can nab both you and your target in a couple of seconds, depending on where the pod is initially.

Comment: I've broken the window to capture an armored target as well.  Was very proud of myself for figuring that out.

Answer (score 1):

Tell you what, acid traps are the things you're looking for. They self-charge and they strip the armour right off your target, after which you can knock them out in the old fashioned way.